# hibernate spring class path not found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am new in spring, and I try to use it with hibernate to create tables from the entity class but it never works, here is my spring-cinfig.xml :

'

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/testeleve"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="yassine"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
    <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
    <property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
    <!-- spring based scanning for entity classes-->
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="Class"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"/>'
```

and here is my test class :

'

```
@Autowired
private static CrudRepository repository;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");


    createEleve(22, "Saint", "Peter");
    createEleve(23, "Jack", " Dorsey");
    createEleve(24, "Sam", "Fox");


}'
```

and here is the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [TestEleve2/resources/spring-config.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [TestEleve2/resources/spring-config.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Comment: i'm using Intellij in my project

Comment: can you add your web.xml?

Comment: my web.xml is empty, i want to try to define my spring-config.xml in my web.xml.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify where is your *spring-config.xml* located. Try something like this:

```
@Autowired
private static CrudRepository repository;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/WEB-INF/resources/spring-config.xml");


createEleve(22, "Saint", "Peter");
createEleve(23, "Jack", " Dorsey");
createEleve(24, "Sam", "Fox");
```

}

**Update**

*mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml*

```
<import resource="spring-config.xml"/>
```

Comment: I already change my class path but it's does not work it's the same exception

Comment: I need another method to get the context from spring-config.xml

Comment: I just fix it by adding this on my web.xml : 

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:spring-config.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

Answer (score 0):

just do one thing put your file spring-config.xml in to the **TestEleve2/resources/** path and try to run program again it has to be run.

Comment: I already do it, I tried many paths but it's just does not work, I think i should define my spring-config.xml in my web.xml.

Comment: ya u have to give that path there u know how to do it? u have to give that path in web.xml

Comment: I just fix it by adding this on my web.xml : 

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:spring-config.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

Comment: ohh ya right or u can put it on any folder na that will be also right.<context-param> <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> <param-value> folder/spring-config.xml </param-value> </context-param>

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in your web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

 <display-name>YourApp</display-name>


<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>YourApp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>YourApp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Here,  web.xml tries to see YourApp-servlet.xml file which is actually your web.xml.
you need to replace your spring-config.xml to  YourApp-servlet.xml .

Here YourApp is your application name. Put it in **webapps** folder.

Comment: I just fix it by adding this on my web.xml : 

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:spring-config.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>